# Greasemonky: How to return count and value of specific div class?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Lets say I have the following on a page:

```
<div class="data-container">John</div>
<div class="data-container">Dave</div>
<div class="data-container">Bob</div>
```

How can I use a javascript in greasemonkey to count each "data-container" class, extract the value (i.e. John) and display this info as a popup? like so:

```
1) John
2) Dave
3) Bob
```

Here is what I got so far that isn't working:

```html
 var elements = document.getElementsByClass("data-container");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){

document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<div class=\"data-container\">/g,"<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size:16px;\"><strong><span style=\"background-color:#ffff00;\">"+ elements[i].className + "</span></strong></span></p><div class=\"data-container\">");
}
```

***Edit***
Thanks cbwll! here is my current working code:

```html
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("data-container");
var contents = [];
var run = [];


for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
contents += elements[i].textContent;
run += i;
final = run + contents;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(final));
```

it produces:

```
0123johndavebobevan
```

which is 0,1,2,3 & John, Dave, Bob, Evan

Any ideas on how the get them paired correctly then get a "\n" in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClass("class");
var contents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    contents += elements[i].textContent;
}
```

//contents would be an array containing the names given in your example.